# Poor rendering performance in ArcGIS Server tiled map service and crashes logged?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, map-service, performance, windows-server-2008

I have a number of map services in ArcGIS Server (10.1, running on 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2) and only one of them is cached.

Caching is configured on-demand as there's no way I can store the full tile set on disk. Also many of the tiles would be empty as my dataset is quite sparse.

Features are only shown when zoomed quite far into the map, which means the service can go some time without being hit (requests are made from ArcGIS JavaScript API v3.2 which doesn't request a tile unless the user is within the visible range).

After a period of inactivity (I'm not sure how much) the first hit to the tile service takes a long time to respond. I can't say for sure if this only happens when generating a new tile on demand, when loading an existing tile, or both. The delay itself is annoying but it's also accompanied by an error in the AGS logs:

```
[Severe] Services containing process crashed. MapServiceName.MapServer instance has crashed
```

The logs provide no more information, and performance picks up after the initial crash.

The map service's data source is a pair of File GeoDatabases, both are registered with the server, both are in EPSG:4326 and output in EPSG:3857 in line with the ESRI base map. Features are very simple (all polygons, usually four-sided shapes) and don't seem to have any geometry problems. The cache disk is nowhere near full and I haven't previously encountered any permissions issues with any of the AGS accounts.

Can anyone suggest why the service might be crashing, why performance might be slow (if not connected to the crash), and where I might want to take my investigation?

Comment: Are u running IIS and the web adapter in this mix? Have you enabled 'Periodically check and repair data connections for idle instances'?  on the map service.

Comment: @Simon yes the web adapter is in play and the services have the default map service configuration, which I think is checking every 30 minutes.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this problem? I'm getting a similar error when publishing/starting a service definition for a geoprocessing service. It appears as though the service gets published. It just won't start. [Here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/79321-Failed-to-start-gp-service) is a link to a description of my problem.

Comment: Please start a new question for your issue.

Comment: If you have not done so already, or not otherwise resolved this problem, then I strongly recommend that you report this problem to support.esri.com.  Don't forget that ["We are not a GIS Software Support Site"](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).